# Why TypeScript compiler does not allow this seemingly valid code?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am having an issue understanding why TypeScript type-checker rejects code that is seemingly valid.

```
export type Fn<I, O> = (value: I) => O
type FInput<F extends Fn<any, any>> = F extends Fn<infer I, any> ? I : never
type FOutput<F extends Fn<any, any>> = F extends Fn<any, infer O> ? O : never

type FnMap = {
  numToInt: Fn<number, number>
  numToStr: Fn<number, string>
  strToNum: Fn<string, number>
  strToStr: Fn<string, string>
}

const fnMap: FnMap = {
  numToInt: (x) => Number(x.toFixed(0)),
  numToStr: (x) => x.toString(10),
  strToNum: (x) => parseInt(x),
  strToStr: (x) => x.toUpperCase(),
} as const

function doWork<T extends keyof FnMap>(key: T, input: FInput<FnMap[T]>): FOutput<FnMap[T]> {
  const fn = fnMap[key]

  return fn(input)
  // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'FOutput<FnMap[T]>'.
  //   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FOutput<FnMap[T]>'.
  // Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  //   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
}
```

Given the above example TypeScript correctly autocompletes the `doWork` function (you can check it out on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiA7APASQDRwDyAfHALxwAUAbgIYA2ArsAFxw4CU5phAsAFBIU6HBjCMYWNHFAxgGACYBndNloZEBdYmKkK02fOWqsASwwAzYFHZaNpAPzs4bDMGrWBQ1GkITxkgYgcooqmFjadjp66DLBRmFqGgTmVjYkcE6ELnBuHlACXsg%20GACytGDkcADeAnC5jAC2ACoQojBs4RhNAEbWBN2NfVDEdQ0tEADKMFCd2IPDBEoz5gDmo-z1y1CtAHJNc1jbawO91htbM63TsybHGKtLKw8bAL6F-ADGEBjLcBZlCpzcqVCi1TbjVrtNiUEBcMikfZDaywgB0MAgaFMIGACkoAAYOBw8GNBtcZjC4dw4CB0VNnqtKABGQkkiHbPYHKhUhFwMC0KBKYDtWHEsYc%20m3UXU2kYgCqYBQUAAwrQhZQxfxXnA1XBvr8YB8LIwMJ8YKYfnAFBAAOrQADWWGacRCxntwEQEAsqhBxEo3jYzRSYgknVEASkgLAAG1mgBdYgcTp%20GARzAg2MJmpjKDAGCMKAYf5R6PeOOUcwBDgCd78AT6v65pSMegwJlVa12qD2ygAcjJbQwMF7BAATABmAAs1f4AHpZ-V6gA9BwfBvwJstmCjju2h19gc3EdwCfTgTzxdwFdAA)).

Is there a specific reason why this fails? Is it possible to express this in any other way?

Comment: TypeScript can't understand generic conditional type operations like this; the recommended way to express this is by using generic indexed access types as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). The refactoring for your code looks like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NaEnpN). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to do! Feel free to write up an answer, I'll accept it as soon as you post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your version isn't working is because the compiler doesn't really try to evaluate [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  Inside `doWork()`, the compiler sees that you're calling a function of type `FnMap[T]` with an argument of type `FInput<FnMap[T]>`, but it isn't able to connect the result of that to `FOutput<FnMap[T]>`.  `FInput` and `FOutput` are conditional types, and `T` is generic, so the compiler doesn't do much analysis.  What it ends up doing is widen `T` to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) and then see that it's calling *some* function in `FnMap` with *some* argument, but it doesn't notice that they match up and it complains both that the input might not be appropriate and that it can't be sure that the output is correct either.

The recommended approach here is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and involves refactoring to represent things explicitly in terms of generic [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) on [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  The goal is that the function is of some type like `(arg: XXX) => YYY` for some `XXX` and `YYY`, and that the input will be of type `XXX`, so the compiler can directly conclude that it produces `YYY`.    To a human being the refactoring might seem like nothing of import has happened, since it's equivalent to your version, but the compiler can follow the logic better.

Here's how I'd do it for your example code.  First let's define your mapping object explicitly and derive a type from it, both of which correspond to your original non-refactored typings:

```
const _fnMap = {
  numToInt: (x: number) => Number(x.toFixed(0)),
  numToStr: (x: number) => x.toString(10),
  strToNum: (x: string) => parseInt(x),
  strToStr: (x: string) => x.toUpperCase(),
}
type _FnMap = typeof _fnMap;
```

Now we can produce three mapped types; one for the inputs, one for the outputs, and one for functions from inputs to outputs:

```
type FnMapArgs = { [K in keyof _FnMap]: Parameters<_FnMap[K]>[0] };
type FnMapRets = { [K in keyof _FnMap]: ReturnType<_FnMap[K]> }
type FnMap = { [K in keyof _FnMap]: (input: FnMapArgs[K]) => FnMapRets[K] };
```

Crucially these types are *not* generic, but specific.  The compiler is able to evaluate *non-generic* conditional types just fine.  So `_FnMap` and `FnMap` are equivalent types, and the compiler understands this... thus we can assign a value of type `_FnMap` to a variable of type `FnMap` without error:

```
const fnMap: FnMap = _fnMap;
```

And now we can write `doWork()` explicitly as generic indexed accesses into our mapped types:

```
function doWork<K extends keyof _FnMap>(type: K, input: FnMapArgs[K]): FnMapRets[K] {
  return fnMap[type](input); // okay
}
```

Inside the function, `fnMap[type]` is of type `FnMap[K]` for generic `K`, which the compiler can evaluate as `(input: FnMapArgs[K]) => FnMapRets[K]` from the definition of `FnMap`.  And since `input` is of type `FnMapArgs[K]`, the compiler happily allows the call, and produces a result of type `FnMapRets[K]`, which is the desired output type of the function.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBFJKiSwLIAKATgPYBGGEYeJpSEAHjPbQBckAgJ4xkAMWAAeAJIAaJAHkAfEgC8SABQA3TAFcIALiSyAlBrVKOpUeKQTZwGPoHSJXbgIjAAJlAcZEGARRWCRFTVNDx5vPwCpaQBLYAAzCFpTMJC1AH5TJBNgCB0Mm2ExSSVXFzcYrx9-QOlw7Iioh084psTWpBT0zNUkfKVCshKy4kJOCvspAFkQGA12GdmyfTAAFXonARNE4C3GDMVjsFPaFXLSC92AZQFaQ5kLq8UoZ5SAcxv12ZfWi7AByW1e0iBv3OJwy-w2SCBj2eEKhwB+n2+6PhnAAvkRyvB6MAvkhUsAljBXpTVgQAZx7ntgAdtNwLOo1GDLhktNwAHQCegSJLcCC+LQABjMZnkt02O3oTxerPZan5gqVvy0AEYpbL6aQkfQuSZeaqkHBaFAIPszfqEUalaa2ZYkOr6ABVGDiWgAYRA1q0MvKuKQAaQRJJAgJ9NS+mA8AESWJSF89AA6vwANbSbZdRoBLMQET0VKBSkqLRFkQmbaKFK1Q5OWruCnLADa2wAuiozIdqgIW4sO921HSEZHSeTVuTKe3q125ZOhLQIEJNOStA3XGYANxy1cCfS0YBk4Bb5w7uUAemvSG2lSQAHI0T8kAAfeVXJ-9ALAehCAGUBJD8oDMMggpzMgT4SAOQ5tjAnY9k+fI3nepAPvYL5Yj8P5JH+AFhlAwGgSA4HCPQUHPrBNSuK2c6jihaFIAAgrQPxbD4QillR2G0L8H5fhkeEEYBxEgWBLAURaIC0OAa4ZEgPF2NBxSlLQTEGkgt6cJh0GviJZCEUBElkVJkEqc+anCah9L4us9kcOQ0BwIgSAPPQGCuMmp50oSxKkgA+rOyy0nKjL7M6RSwrQ5pclcvICkKIpipK0r2hsjJOqy0XcrFrrupq6I6nqcpGiaOWIjh5qWtatpshlgLPMiyq8iYr7mu6Xo+v6gbBnZ5SWYFw4rJoKk8cFCH7vSlkjWxPwBJouBIO2ADS-SntWE0jV2JjULJ8neFa0jDQha09u2EpdkguLTbMs0IQASmui14Ct60pEgW1lqdlK7Ugz1HieeknSN51qPZ92PiNtLvRtX3FttCH-Rejblss81QOd5ojYDWOrddt0xrMy5npS1KhZok2UtN5RxgmSYpmmma0Dm62xAWCMlj9I2VipJirfWl4snN7H412fbozAePnWsCKHsep4hYhKldqjV4DdMJMBSu0D6BgAjaqszPZloT4RcyT6KAATAAzAALGY5Q6ZwAB6uTE5wpOrlA+sCNbxsZqb5tbC1VtIHbjvO+hpDuzGHCOYQuJAA)